# C# FORM with image and auto close

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a problem I made a new form, with background img, and all I need and its working like I wanted, but I also need to auto close it after 5 or 10 seconds.

I searched on google all day ... but no tutorial was good.
I use Visual Studio 2013.

Can you boys help me please...
I'm desperate right now... its almost 10 hours since I'm trying.
You are my last hope.
Thanks

this.close() dosen't did it, or I made it wrong but i doubt that.
Application.Exit fail
timers give errors...

```
//form
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Cerum_HS
{
    public partial class CERUM_HS : Form
    {
        public CERUM_HS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Rectangle r = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height);
        }
    }
}


//main.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;
//using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Cerum_HS
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>


        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new CERUM_HS());

            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Interval = 10;

            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10);

            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

            aTimer.AutoReset = false;

            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
            Application.Exit();
            //this.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened? Where did you call it? What errors did you get?

Comment: I did called the function from both files. Sometimes it dosent give error but the app dosent close. I will post the code right now.

Comment: where is your call of `this.Close()`? Don't you use a timer? probably running in a separate thread?

Comment: Look now i added my last try... still doesnt close..

Comment: you could try and put the timer into the CERUM_HS class, start it in the `load` event and try `this.Close()`

Comment: Not in main ? In form? I will try right now.

Comment: Thankssss a lot !!!!!! you saved me.....

Comment: Bogdan could you check and verify the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment seemed to help, I thought I write it down as an answer.

```
public partial class CERUM_HS : 
{
    // here is the timer for the automatic closing
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public CERUM_HS()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Rectangle r = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height);
    }

    private void Form_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // start here the timer when the form is loaded
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 10;

        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10);

        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

        aTimer.AutoReset = false;

        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Close the Application when this event is fired
        Application.Exit();
    }

}
```

Bogdan please comment if this implementation is how it worked for you in the end.

Comment: well this.Close(); will give error replace with Application.Exit();

Answer (score 1):

I would put a PictureBox and timer on your form (set to 5000 ms), click on the Tick event, and use this code:

```
namespace Image
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // set picture box to image of interest
            // size and position form appropriately
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```